# Issue with creating an edit view in django

Tags: django

Trying to allow users to edit their data. However, when the link that would take them to the edit page is clicked, I get a "NoReverseMatch" error. I'm pretty sure that it has to do with my view. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm stuck like chuck...

models.py

```
class Rider(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    birthdate = models.DateField(verbose_name=None, auto_now=False)

    NOVICE = 'N'
    BEGINNER = 'B'
    COMPETENT = 'C'
    PROFICIENT = 'P'
    EXPERT = 'E'

    skill_level_choices = [
        ('NOVICE', 'Novice'),
        ('BEGINNER', 'Beginner'),
        ('COMPETENT', 'Competent'),
        ('PROFICIENT', 'Proficient'),
        ('EXPERT', 'Expert')
    ]
    skill_level = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices = skill_level_choices,
        default = NOVICE,        
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.last_name + ', ' +self.first_name
```

views.py

```
def edit_rider(request, riders_id):
    riders = Rider.objects.get(id=riders_id)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = RiderForm(instance=riders)
    else:
        form = RiderForm(instanse=riders, data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('riding_schedule:index'))

    context = {'riders':riders, 'form':form}
    return render(request, 'riders/edit_rider.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
    path('edit_rider/<int:riders_id>', views.edit_rider, name = 'edit_rider'),
```

edit_rider.html

```
{% extends "riding_schedule/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <p>Edit rider:</p>

  <form action="{% url 'riders:edit_rider' rider.id %}" method='post'>
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <button name = "submit">save changes</button>
  </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /riders/edit_rider/8
Exception Value: Reverse for 'edit_rider' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['riders/edit_rider/(?P[0-9]+)$']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your template, there is no `rider` variable, only `riders`. Although that does not look like good nomenclature.

You can rename `riders` to `rider`:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def edit_rider(request, riders_id):
    rider = Rider.objects.get(id=riders_id)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = RiderForm(instance=rider)
    else:
        form = RiderForm(instanse=rider, data=request.POST)
        if form is valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('riding_schedule:index')

    context = {'rider': rider, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'riders/edit_rider.html', context)
```

Then in your form there is a `rider` variable, and thus the `{% url ... %}` tag will succeed:

```
<form action="{% url 'riders:edit_rider' rider.id %}" method='post'>
```

Comment: Thanks!! I knew it was going to be something simple... I tried to up vote you, but I don't have enough rep. Thanks again.